# Why is Django not redirecting to url compare files?

Tags: python, django

I am uploading two files, then comparing them with xxhash algorithm and return same if they are same or different otherwise, however when submitting the form containing the files it is not redirecting it to the function in views that does the magic, and it is giving me error 404:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/post?file1=f.txt&file2=t.txt Using the
> URLconf defined in hashhosh.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in
> this order:
>
> admin/ [name='home'] login/ [name='login'] compare-files/
> [name='compare-files'] The current path, post, didn’t match any of these

why is that happening?
urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
    path('compare-files/', views.compare_files_view, name='compare-files'),  # Update the URL pattern
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.shortcuts import render
import xxhash
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def login_view(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def compare_files_view(request):  # Update the view name
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'file1' in request.FILES and 'file2' in request.FILES:
        file1 = request.FILES['file1']
        file2 = request.FILES['file2']
        result = "Same" if compare_files(file1, file2) else "Different"
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'result': result})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')

def compare_files(file1, file2):
    hash1 = xxhash.xxh64(file1.read()).hexdigest()
    hash2 = xxhash.xxh64(file2.read()).hexdigest()
    return hash1 == hash2
```

home.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        Yo wassup {{ user.username }}!
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'compare-files' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <br>file 1: <br>
            <input type = 'file' name="file1"/>
            <br>file 2: <br>
            <input type = 'file' name="file2"/>
            <br><button type="submit">Compare Files</button>
        </form>
        {% if result %}
            <p>Comparison Result: {{ result }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <p>please Login</p>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for hashhosh project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-5q$^nk1tp-fe)w9x25xqg3sy0fg98bhx7rm8gu!lk%b2*z_tfw'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hashhosh.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hashhosh.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'hashhosh.backends.xxhash_backend.XXHashAuthBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of fixes (at least the ones I can spot now):

1. You appear to be mixing up your project level urls.py with your app level urls.py. Your project level urls.py is found in the same directory as your settings.py and it should look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('appname.urls')),  # Change appname to the actual name of your app
]
```

In your app directory (this is where your views.py is), create a urls.py and add:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'appname'    # Change appname to the name of your app.
urlpatterns = [
    path('home_view/', views.home_view, name='home_view'),
    path('login_view/', views.login_view, name='login_view'),
    # Add other url patterns here
]
```

2. You did not include your app in the list of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. Include it as shown:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'appname',   # Your app name. Please change to your app name
]
```

3. You have not provided your appname in your code. Did you even create an app? Please see the [official django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/).